# If the number of distinct five-digits $1A54B$ is divided by $24$ , then the remainder is 15, what is the sum of the different values ​A can take?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> If the number of distinct five-digits $1A54B$ is divided by  $24$ , then the remainder is $15$, what is the sum of the different values ​​A can take?

a) 6

b) 8

c) 10

d) 12 .

e) 15

Comment: Ok, so where are you struggling? Note that $1A54B + 9$ is a multiple of $24$. Now, can $B$ be zero? If not, what does the number $1A54B+9$ looks like(as in, what are its digits)? Now that is a  multiple of $24$ so use the divisibility tests for $3$ and $8$.

Comment: $A=8$ and $B=3$ are valid. The answer is b) of course.  Show please your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1A54B =10000 + 1000*A + 540 + B=$

$(24*416 +16) + (24*41 + 16)A+ (22*24+ 12)+B=$

$24(416+41*A+22) + 16*A + 28 + B = $

$24(416+41*A+23) + 16*A + 4 + B$.

So there is some $m$ where $16*A + 4 + B = 24m + 15$

or $16*A = 24m + 11 - B$

$8|16*A$ and $8|24m$ so $8|11-B$ but the only multiple of $8$ between $11 - 9=2$ and $11 + 0=11$ is $8$. so $11 -B = 8$ and $B=3$.
So $16*A = 24m + 8$ and $2*A = 3m + 1$.

Okay..... so if $2*A = 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18$ and the ones that can be $3m+1$ are $2*A = 4, 10,16$ so $A = 2,5, 8$

But the problem said the digits are distinct so $A \ne 1,5,4,$ or $3$ so $A\ne 5$.

So $A = 2$ or $8$.

And the sum is $10$.

=====

That was the real hard way.

But if when you divide by $24$ you have remainder $15$ means there is an $\omega$ so that $1A54B = 24\omega + 15= 3(8\omega + 5)$ so $1A54B$ is divisible by $3$.  And $24\omega + 15 = 8(3\omega + 1) + 7$ so when you divide $1A54B$ you get remainder of $7$.

$1000 = 8*125$ so $1A000$ is divisible by $8$ so $54B$ will have remainder $7$ when divided by $8$ and $54B = 540 + B$.  $540= 8*67+4$ so $4+B=7$.  So $B = 3$.

So $1A54B = 1A543$.  And this is divisible by $3$ so the sum of the digits are a multiple of $3$.  $1+A+5+4+3 = 13+A$.  For the sum to be a multiple of $3$, $A$ must equal $2,5,$ or $8$.

=====

For what its worth: $12543 = 24*522+15$ and $18543 =24*722 + 15$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N=1A54B +1$.  We know that $N\equiv16\pmod {24}$, so $N\equiv0\pmod8$.

1000 is divisible by 8, so $54B+1$ must be divisible by 8.  A quick calculator check ensures that $B=3$.

Since 24 and 15 are both multiples of 3, $1A543$ is divisble by 3.  This means that the sum of its digits is divisble by 3.  Therefore, $A$ must be 2, 5, or 8.  But the problem states that the digits must be distinct, so 5 is not allowed.  Therefor the answer is 10.

Comment: Why do you say $1A544B$ is divisible by $8$?  It *isn't* divisible by $24$ (it has remainder $15$).

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the 15 part of the problem.  Thank you for pointing it out!  My solution is corrected.

Comment: "If $1A54B$ is divided by 8, then its remainder must be 7"  why @ Matthew Daly?

Comment: solution updated with more explanation.